# Read the source code of an iframe on another domain

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

I need read a source code content an iframe, this is a cross domain

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document.getElementById("iFrame")).ready(function(){
     var iframe = document.getElementById('iFrame');
     var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
    });
```

Any chance to read the source code of my iframe on another domain?

Comment: If cross domain is possible, people will do all sort of things.

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: If you control both domains, it's trivial to communicate between them.

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter points out, this is a cross domain request so it's not going to work as an AJAX request. You might try making an endpoint on your own domain that you can submit an AJAX request to which in turn retrieves the content from the URL server-side.

Answer (score 1):

There's HTML5 postMessage and there's URL Hash polling (for browsers that don't support HTML5).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

---

If you don't have control of both domains, then you're stuck with a server side solution. Send an ajax request to your in-domain server with the URL as a parameter and have it return the HTML.

---

**EDIT** Because of the downvotes I'll elaborate on URL Hash polling a bit. Despite not having read access to the URL because of cross-domain restriction you still have access to set the URL Hash (text after the # character at the end of the URL). So you set the hash, which doesn't cause a page reload and the script can 'poll' for changes to that hash.

Comment: If the iframe is on another domain, he will not even be able to read the current URL loaded in the iframe.

Comment: @Ivan Zuzak - You should read the links I posted. Apparently access to the URL Hash (stuff after the # character at the end of the url, not the cryptographic hash) is still available (despite cross-domain restrictions) which is why the method is called URL Hash polling.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit more on your solution. Which iframe/window does what and when? Are you suggesting that the child iframe sets the hash fragment of the parent window, and the value of that hash is the URL loaded in the iframe? If that is the idea, why not just use postMessage and send the whole source of the iframe?

Comment: Anyway, what I was referring to in my first comment was the idea of using a server. The problem with that is getting the URL from within the parent window which it would then pass to the server. Because if you don't control the iframe - it cant give the parent the URL, and the parent can't read the URL itself because of SOP. And if you can control the iframe - then you don't need the server because you can use a pure client-side solution.

Comment: @Ivan Zuzak - postMessage isn't available on older browsers.